# ggplot2: Add box (goem_rect?) below plot with color gradient based on values

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, geom-bar

I'm trying to plot the number of seedlings that emerge each year since a fire. Number of seedlings is on the y-axis, years since fire is on the x-axis. I want to add a box or rectangle below this plot that shows the values of another variable (let's say rainfall) that changes each year. Like this:

[image: [Ideal plot with gradient bar at the bottom.]]

I've managed to do so by adding a separate rectangle with `geom_rect()` for each year, but is there a way to do this without 10 separate rectangles? Especially so that I only have to specify color modifications once and not in 10 different calls of `geom_rect()`??

These two ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734630/timeline-bar-with-colour-fill-based-on-time-series-value-r-ggplot), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742804/ggplot2-add-a-gradient-colored-square-according-to-values)) older posts have helped get me to where I am now, but I'd like to do this in only a few lines of code. I haven't been able to get `scale_fill_gradient()` to work, but maybe that's part of the solution?

Data here:

```
yr_since <- c(1:10)
density <- c(23, 58, 68, 126, 154, 103, 90, 94, 73, 59)
rain <- c(3, 6, 8, 5, 8, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2)
data <-as.data.frame(cbind(yr_since, density, rain))
```

Current (ghastly) code here:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = yr_since)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=density), width = 0.95) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0), drop=FALSE, labels = yr_since) +
  labs(x = "Years since fire", y = "Density (stems/ha)") 

plot + 
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 0.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 1.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[1])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 1.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 2.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[2])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 2.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 3.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[3])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 3.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 4.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[4])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 4.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 5.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[5])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 5.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 6.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[6])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 6.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 7.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[7])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 7.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 8.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[8])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 8.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 9.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[9])) +
  geom_rect(data=data,
            aes(xmin = 9.5, ymin = -5, 
                xmax = 10.5, ymax = 0,
                fill = rain[10]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an additional `geom_col` call to add them, with a fixed negative value for `y`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(yr_since = c(1:10),
                   density = c(23, 58, 68, 126, 154, 103, 90, 94, 73, 59),
                   rain = c(3, 6, 8, 5, 8, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2))

ggplot(data, aes(x = yr_since, y = density)) +
    geom_col(width = 0.95) + 
    geom_col(aes(y = -5, fill = rain), width = 1) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = data$yr_since, expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-5, max(data$density) * 1.05)) + 
    labs(x = "Years since fire", 
         y = "Density (stems/ha)")
```

[image]

Adjust as you like.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, alistaire -- that's perfect.